# Why can java not read rt.jar?

Tags: io, java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to run a java program that uses a `PrintWriter` and calls the `PrintWriter.format()` method. It runs fine in Eclipse, but running from the command line, I get this:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06/jre/lib/rt.jar: error reading zip file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Formatter
```

Does this mean Java can't read a `.jar` from its own library? Anyone know a fix for this?

I'm using Java 1.6, as the filepath suggests.

**Edit:** It also works fine when I run from the command line on a linux machine. Just not on Windows (through PuTTY, if that's relevant).

Comment: your classpath is not set up correctly

Comment: how should it be set up?

Comment: what is the command you are using in the command line? generally you will need to use java -cp "path to jar" yourProgram. if the jar isn't in a folder in your classpath

Comment: can you show how you are calling your program command line?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi the exact error above happens when I call a bash script that invokes `java -cp` on a hard-coded jar with a classpath specified as an argument.

But I get a similar error when I don't use the script. From a directory containing the jarred project and jarred referenced libraries (not including the JRE System Library), I enter
    `java -cp project.jar:* path/to/MainClass [args]`
And I get this:
    `NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Vector`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_06/jre/lib/rt.jar: error reading zip file
```

It looks like your copy of `rt.jar` has become corrupted: some program has overwritten it with garbage. To fix it you should get a fresh copy from somewhere, or reinstall the JDK.

Comment: But it works when I run it from a linux machine, too. So `rt.jar` must have the right stuff in it. Doesn't that there's something wrong with the file path (at least when I run the program from a Windows machine)?

Comment: `/usr/java/..` is a Unix file path. How come you are seeing that path on a Windows machine? How are you running your program?

Comment: Ah that's it! Or at least part of it. I'm running the program through a bash script that's written to work in a Linux system.

But the problem persists when I try to run it without the script. When I enter `java -cp project.jar:* path/to/MainClass [args]` I get this: `NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Vector` what am I missing?

Comment: Which port of `bash` are you using, cygwin? What's in the script? Are you using the Cygwin or Windows version of java? (Does Cygwin even have a version of Java of its own?)

Comment: The script invokes `java -cp` on this jar (the absolute file path to which is hard-coded into the script) with the classpath specified by an argument handed to the script.

What's cygwin? How can I tell if I'm using it and what would that mean?

Comment: If you don't know what it is you're not using it. How are you running a bash script *on Windows*?

Comment: But isn't putty for connecting to remote machines via SSH? So you are not actually running the program on windows, but on a remote (Unix?) machine?

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry

Comment: worked for me after replacing to new java